# is LSH works for zip,jar, wim, iso or any kind of compressed files?

Tags: file, duplicates, data-science, minhash, lsh

I am wanted to know will [LSH(Locality senstive hashing)](https://medium.com/engineering-brainly/locality-sensitive-hashing-explained-304eb39291e4) work for any kind of files to find nearest neighbors ?
Means i noticed everywhere, using text file only but i want to find for wim,iso and zip files.

So will it work for the wim, iso and zip files as well.

Thanks in advance

Comment: LSH cannot deal with compressed data. You will need to decompress it first. Additionally, ISO-files will likely have many sections in common such as metadata and format specifiers which might make them match other ISOs that have completely different content. Having only a cursory knowledge about LSH I would assume that you need "proper data" that does not have such overhead such as formatting codes, or being compressed. For instance, if you change all the *text* in a html document, but leave all html tags as-is, I'm assuming LSH might trigger off of that for some documents.

Comment: Thankyou so much @LasseV.Karlsen

Answer (score 0):

There is a paper which might be interesting in this context:

Edward Raff, Joe Aurelio. PyLZJD: An Easy to Use Tool for Machine Learning in
Proceedings of the 18th Python in Science Conference, 97-102.
http://hdl.handle.net/11603/14971

It actually defines a metric for compressed data, which could be used for LSH.